# Limit of ratio of matrices' powers applied to vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A=\left(\begin{array}{rr}3 & -1 \\ 1 & 5\end{array}\right)$, $B=\left(\begin{array}{rr}6 & -2 \\ 2 & 2\end{array}\right)$. Find $\lim _{N \rightarrow \infty}\left\|A^N(x)\right\| /\left\|B^N(x)\right\|$ as a function of $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Attempt: I tried to find the eigenstates of the matrices, and find that they both have 4 as repeated eigenvalue. Now the Jordan block to the $n$th power is $\left(\begin{array}{rr}4^n & n4^{n-1} \\ 0 & 4^n\end{array}\right)$. The factor $4^{n-1}$ can be taken out and canceled, so we are left off with something like $\left\|V\left(\begin{array}{rr}4 & n \\ 0 & 4\end{array}\right)V^{-1}x\right\|$ and something similar at the bottom, which is still pretty complicated and messy.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it turns out it is not as messy as I thought. However I would still like to hear comments on my current solution, to make it rigorous.

$A^n=4^{n-1}\left(\begin{array}{rr}
1 & -1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{rr}
4 & n \\
0 & 4
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{rr}
0 & -1 \\
-1 & -1
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{rr}
1 & -1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{array}\right)=4^{n-1}\left(4I+n\left(\begin{array}{rr}
-1 & -1 \\
1 & 1
\end{array}\right)\right)$.

Similarly $B^n=4^{n-1}\left(4I+2n\left(\begin{array}{rr}
1 & -1 \\
1 & -1
\end{array}\right)\right)$.

So I think $\lim _{N \rightarrow \infty}\left\|A^N(x)\right\| /\left\|B^N(x)\right\|=
\lim _{N \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\left\|4x+n\left(\begin{array}{c}
-(x_1+x_2)  \\
x_1+x_2 
\end{array}\right)\right\| }{\left\|4x+2n\left(\begin{array}{}
x_1-x_2)  \\
x_1-x_2 
\end{array}\right)\right\|}=
\frac{(x_1+x_2)^2}{2(x_1-x_2)^2}$, where $x=(x_1,x_2)^{T}$.

Please let me know if there is a better way to do this or if this is incorrect.